# iOS App distribution - Archiving an .ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, in-house-distribution

I have an `.ipa` file which is signed with an Enterprise Certificate and using an inHouse distribution profile. I do not have the original source code with me. When I went through the distribution article in Dev center, I understood that it has to be archived for distribution purpose. I do not know how to archive an .ipa file. Could you please assist me in this? I'm new to this iOS development world.

Comment: If you have the `.ipa`, it has already likely been through the archiving process. What you need to go along with the `.ipa` is a `.plist` file (this usually created at the same time as the `.ipa`). iOS devices use the `.plist` file to install the application contained in the `.ipa`.

Comment: Thanks Mike. How do I distribute this App by hosting in a server? Could you please let me know?

Comment: There you go. I had to make a couple assumptions based on your question, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to assume everything was built and signed properly, with the proper provisioning profiles and distribution certificates.

You need the `myApp.ipa` and the `myApp.plist` generated by XCode, there may be others ways, but generating these via Xcode is the easiest. Once you have both of these files, upload them to your server (e.g. `public_html/app/myApp.ipa` and `public_html/app/myApp.plist`).

Your users navigate to your download page via Safari. On this page you include a link like the following:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://mydomain.com/app/myApp.plist">Install the app</a>
```

It is pointing to the `myApp.plist`. This must have (among other things) an item like the following (not sure about the exact format at the moment, but it is easy to spot if you open the .plist file in text editor):

```
<key>url</key>
<string>http://mydomain.com/app/myApp.ipa</string>
```

This URL is also usually added during the archive in XCode, but it can be easliy edited. It points to the `.ipa` (which really a zip file containg the executable and other resources like images).

When users tap "Install the app" in Safari, it will read the plist file, and if everything was successful up to this point, will prompt the user to install the application.

Comment: I don't have MyApp.plist with me. Since I don't have the source code with me, I used a Re-Signer application to re-sign the application using my Enterprise Profile. Is it possible to get the MyApp.plist file? In MyApp.ipa, I see info.plist, I don't think this is the one.

Comment: @Apps I don't think so. `info.plist` is usually used as settings file for the executable. I try see what I can find. But who ever provided the `.ipa` should have the `.plist` that was generated at the same time.

Comment: @Apps You can try to build a `.plist` file manually. I have never done it so I can't tell you how well it works. Found an sample ongithub. https://gist.github.com/frischmilch/b15d81eabb67925642bd#file_manifest.plist